# Non-default version of Boto3 running in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have some Python using Boto3 running in an AWS CodeBuild project (as a phase in CodePipeline, in case that matters).  However, I noticed that it's running an old version of Boto3 that doesn't have some features I need.  How can I get CodeBuild to install the new version?

My buildspec currently has this line, but it's defaulting to the old version.

```
install:
     commands:
           - pip3 install --quiet boto3
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the way I solved it was by specifying the boto3 version in the Makefile that gets run in the Project's buildspec.yml.

Here's the relevant part from the Buildspec:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - make -f tests/Makefile -n install
```

Here's the relevant part from the Makefile:

```
install:
    pip3 install --quiet 'boto3>=1.9.114' --force-reinstall
```